# How to upload and convert XLSX file to JSON using ember.js

Tags: javascript, excel, ember.js, xlsx

I am trying to allow the user to upload an XLSX file to be converted to a JSON or CSV file to be parsed through on the back-end.  I am using node.js, and tried several packages including the read-excel-file 
(https://github.com/catamphetamine/read-excel-file/blob/master/README.md)

```
readXlsxFile(file).then(function(data) {
let jsondata = JSON.parse(data);
-do something with jsondata-
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual place to look for add-ons would be [Ember Observer](https://emberobserver.com/?query=xlsx) but the options available seem have a status of Work In Progress - they might be a useful place to look though to get some inspiration for how to proceed.

There are plenty of options on [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=xlsx%20parse%20json). You can import one of those into your project using the new add-on `ember-auto-import` or, if you'd rather do the hard work yourself, the [Ember guides provide some guidance on manually importing](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/addons-and-dependencies/managing-dependencies/#toc_compiling-assets).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [js-xlsx](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx). Add it as bower dependecy and add its imports to your `ember-cli-build` file as:

```
app.import('bower_components/js-xlsx/dist/jszip.js');
app.import('bower_components/js-xlsx/dist/xlsx.min.js');
```

Handle it as the documentation's [parsing-workbooks](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx#parsing-workbooks) section shows. (`handleFile` function is explaining it well.)

Comment: To quote the latest Ember docs: "`bower_components` ... works, but is recommended against, unless you have no other choice. Even bower recommends not to use itself anymore." (https://guides.emberjs.com/release/addons-and-dependencies/managing-dependencies/#toc_compiling-assets)